# What is the best way of sliding section of html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

I have a hidden section in my Html template (Am using Django templates), the hidden section is a login form, i want when a user clicks some login text(link), the html text hidding the form should slide downwards revealing the form.

I have a feeling this can be done in Javascript!

Am using django, please give step by step details of how to include the javascript in my project.

Help

Gath

Answer (score 3):

To continue on Travis' response;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggleForm").click(function () {
      $("#loginForm").slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
  </script>
<div id='toggleForm'>Show Login</div>
<div id='loginForm'>
 Your form goes here!
<div>
```

i.e. slideToggle() is your friend.

Comment: I knew there was something like that. I thought you could pass an effect into the toggle method, but I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Django, but I can tell you that [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) will do exactly what you want. You will need to include the JQuery library, and then use the slideDown() and slideUp() functions to show your form.

Here's a rough example of what you are after. Check the [JQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideDown#speedcallback) for more information

```
<script>
    $("#toggleForm").click(function () {
      if ($("#loginForm").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#loginForm").slideDown("slow");
      } else {
        $("#loginForm").slideUp("slow");
      }
    });
</script>

<div id='toggleForm'>Show Login</div>
<div id='loginForm'>
 Your form goes here!
<div>
```

Comment: I think you should wrap that code in an onDomReady() function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), something like this should do the trick

```
$('.login-link').bind('click', function(e) { // bind event handler to click of login link

    $('#login-panel').slideDown(); // slide down the panel
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link taking you to the js disabled login page

});
```

Of course, this is only a starting point, as you'd ideally want to be able to slide it up and down on each consecutive click.